# Regular Expression for float and percentage

Tags: c#, regex

I need regex patterns for floating point numbers with optional `%` sign at the end like

```
12.32
12.32%
0.32
.32
.32%
```

arbitrary length of numbers on left and right of floating point numbers. I need this to validate input in asp.net mvc app
**UPDATE:**
forgot following combinations

```
12%
35
45%
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This regex should do it for you...

```
\d*\.\d+%?
```

Which means... zero or more digits (`\d*`) followed by a period (escaped `\.`) followed by one or more digits (`\d+`) followed by an optional % (`%?`)

---

Update: match whole numbers

```
\d*\.?\d+%?
```

[image: regex diagram]

Comment: thanks Billy can u tell me compact regex for validating email. currently i m using regex from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/EmailRegexValidator.aspx

Comment: matching emails with regex is really difficult, because there are so many variations of valid email addresses. Generally, I would just check to see that there is something on each side of an @ symbol, and leave the validating to an inteligent person (hopefully the user is one of these). I have been tripped up by many badly written email validators not allowing for example `some+thing@whatever.com` because of the perfectly valid `+` in there. Also, the regex needs to change as more top level domains are defined, so what works today, might exclude valid emails tomorrow. It is a minefield!

Comment: any simple one that u r using?

Comment: Also - billy@143.256.744.233 is a valid email address, and although unusual, should be permitted by comprehensive validator and rarely is. But the main point to considder with email validation, is that even if it is a valid syntax for an email, there is no guaruntee that it is a real email address. billy@example.com is valid - but I doubt that the email address exists. So, if you do use email validation, I would make it not enforce it's rule, but maybe gently warn that it does not appear to the system to be valid. The regex you linked to seems thorough, more concise regex will be less accurate

Comment: generally, I just check to see that there is an @ in there and something either side of it - so `.+@.+`, which is not very thorough as it allows a lot of false positives, but it does allow for all emails, and future modifications to domains etc...

Comment: i just noted that i forgot to mention numbers like 12 and 12% in my question. can u plz tell me how can i amend this regex to match these values as well

Comment: i just changed it to \d*(\.)?\d+%? and it seems to be working. is there any problem with this pattern

Comment: I think your pattern is fine. You can take out the brackets if you want and just have `\d*\.?\d+%?`

Comment: It can detect number with percentage kind of pattern, but for validation purpose I need regex which specifically return true for above pattern not for 'abcd@0.3%'.
`/\d*\.\d+%?/.test('abcd@0.3%')` is also returning true which we don't want, kindly help help me out.

Comment: `/^\d*\.?\d+%?$/`, this would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
\d*\.\d{1,}%?
```

This matches all your cases.

**ADD**:
I answered the question in the comment about the `{1,}`: since I wasn't sure if single digit after the decimal point would be a valid input for you (all your examples have at least 2 digits after the point) I didn't use the plus-notation but rather indicated the number of digits explicitly. Here the first number indicates the minimal and the second number (omitted here) the maximal number of the digits after the point. If you want that all your input values have at least 2 digits after the point, use `{2,}` instead of `{1,}`.

Comment: Why use `{1,}`? Doesn't `+` work the same (`+` = Repeated one or more times)

Comment: Since all examples provided by the question starter contained at least 2 digit after the decimal point I wasn't sure if only a single digit or no digits at all (e.g., just the decimal point) would be a valid input too. That's why I preferred to leave the number here, so that the person who is not expert in regexps can easily configure the number of decimal digits after the point.

Comment: you could also use `\d\d` for exactly two digits, or `\d\d+` for two or more digits, which in this circumstance would be quite readable I think

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+%?$
```

This will work for  :

1. 12.34
2. 34.56%
3. 37
4. 65%
5. 123.456
6. .45
7. .34%